# Renaming namespace in Java Bindings Library Project - Generator error

Tags: xamarin

Following the directions at http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/api_metadata_reference/#Metadata.xml_Transform_File

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.mycompany.myapi]" name="managedName">MyCompany.MyAPI</attr>

In this example, a Java library with a package 
com.mycompany.myapi is mapped to the .NET namespace MyCompany.MyAPI.
```

I am trying to rename the namespace of a binding library project I created. The project successfully compiles before trying to do any transformations. Looking at the generated `obj/debug/api.xml` file the first few lines show

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<api>
<package name="android_serialport">
...
```

So to change the namespace from `android_serialport` to something like `MyCompany.Ports.IO` I am editing `Transofrms/Metadata.xml` to be

```
<metadata>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='android_serialport]" name="managedName">MyCompany.Ports.IO</attr>
</metadata>
```

However, with this added line I get an error that is rather cryptic:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Bindings.targets(5,5): Error MSB6006: **"generator.exe" exited with code -532462766.** (MSB6006) (SerialPort)

The library I'm trying to create bindings to is was created in Android Studio to generate an aar. Without the transformation line added, everything compiles and I am able to reference it with no problem.

Anyone have experience with binding library transformations failing?

Comment: Try building the library in a console window using xbuild or msbuild, maybe there's something in the logs to help you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx - Look at the verbosity parameter

Comment: Thanks @Machinarius. I actually noticed a typo in the metadata attribute's path right after posting the question. I went ahead and answered hoping to help others in the future.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is coming from the bindings generator. I was unable to find any docs on the error code, but it's being thrown due to a typo in the edited `Transforms/Metadata.xml` file:

```
path="/api/package[@name='android_serialport]"
```

should be

```
path="/api/package[@name='android_serialport']"
```

Notice the missing **'** at the end of the `@name`. It's too bad the error message doesn't lead you to this.